# Where does crontab get the email address of the user it emails / where are user email addresses set?

Tags: cron, email

I am trying to familiarize myself with crontab.  I know that it is supposed to send an email containing the output of jobs to the user that scheduled them however, I can see in the `syslog` that the address crontab is sending emails to is not a "local" one (as if I were to type `mail -s "email here" username`) but an external email address (like user@example.com).

Can someone tell me from where this email is derived and how I can set the users' email address to something else?

This could be because I have a top-level domain associated with my instance (I can see in the log the emails are being sent there), however, I actually have two domain names pointed to this server so I don't know how crontab is choosing or what would happen if there were no domain on this machine.

In short I am just trying to figure out where this default email address is set.

Comment: On what operating system? The capabilities to send emails to non-local users depends on the cron implementation. And what MTA (mail server software, e.g. postfix, exim, etc.) are you using? It may be the MTA that's doing the rewriting.

Comment: This is for Ubuntu Linux. What is strange to me is that, until I installed `mailutils`, I could not even use the `mail` program, therefore I do not know how `cron` would have sent an email (even to local users).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man 5 crontab

> ```
>        If MAILTO is defined (and non-empty), mail  is  sent
>        to the user so named.  MAILTO may also be used to direct mail to multi‐
>        ple recipients by separating recipient users with a comma.
> ```

Comment: Good find! Unfortunately this does not explain where mail is sent if MAILTO is not defined and does not answer my question.

Comment: user@`cat /etc/mailname` or how you configured your mta. it's not crontab's job to choose address, it always addresses the local user.

Comment: Ah, there is the answer I am looking for.  So it appends the users' name onto how the mta was configured.  I see, thank you.